# Enumerating sequences in sorted PySpark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a Spark DF that I'm trying to apply additional grouping to. It's a sorted dataframe of the form

```
--------------------------------------
| id |   timestamp    | head_indices |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |     23         | 1            |
| 1  |     24         | 0            |
| 1  |     25         | 0            |
| 1  |     55         | 1            |
| 1  |     56         | 0            |
| 1  |     57         | 0            |
| 1  |     58         | 0            |
| 1  |     75         | 1            |
| 1  |     77         | 0            |
| 2  |     43         | 1            |
| 2  |     44         | 0            |
| 2  |     45         | 0            |
--------------------------------------
```

In this data, each `id` has some number of rows that are contiguous, where the start of each sequence is indicated by `head_indices`. I'm trying to use `head_indices` to enumerate contiguous sequences into a new column, such that the transformation afterwards would look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id |   timestamp    | head_indices | seq_id |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  |     23         | 1            | 1      |
| 1  |     24         | 0            | 1      |
| 1  |     25         | 0            | 1      |
| 1  |     55         | 1            | 2      |
| 1  |     56         | 0            | 2      |
| 1  |     57         | 0            | 2      |
| 1  |     58         | 0            | 2      |
| 1  |     75         | 1            | 3      |
| 1  |     77         | 0            | 3      |
| 2  |     43         | 1            | 1      |
| 2  |     44         | 0            | 1      |
| 2  |     45         | 0            | 1      |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Where `seq_id` represents the index of the sequence, separated by `id`.

Any guidance would be welcome

Comment: does seq id only alternate between 1 and 2, based on head_indices?

Comment: No, if there was a third 1 row in head_indices where the id was also 1, the seq_id would further increment to 3. I'll update the example real quick

Comment: Just use sum + WindowSpec: `df.selectExpr('*', 'sum(head_indices) OVER (Partition By id Order by timestamp) as seq_id').show()`

Comment: @jxc i cant believe i never thought of that

Comment: @jxc That's perfect, thanks! Do you want to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I used 10 as the rangebetween as a safe measure, if the number of consecutive timestamps is greater than 10 or the difference between the timestamp intervals is less than 10, then 10 will have to be changed. It is more dynamic then my last answer.

```
w=Window().partitionBy("id", "head_indices").orderBy("timestamp")
w2=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("timestamp")).rangeBetween(-10,0)
df.withColumn("head1", F.row_number().over(w))\
.withColumn("head2", F.when(F.col("head_indices")==1, F.col("head1")).otherwise(F.col("head_indices")))\
.withColumn("seq_id", F.first("head2").over(w2))\
.drop("head1","head2")\
.orderBy("id","timestamp").show()

+---+---------+------------+------+
| id|timestamp|head_indices|seq_id|
+---+---------+------------+------+
|  1|       23|           1|     1|
|  1|       24|           0|     1|
|  1|       25|           0|     1|
|  1|       55|           1|     2|
|  1|       56|           0|     2|
|  1|       57|           0|     2|
|  1|       75|           1|     3|
|  1|       76|           0|     3|
|  1|       77|           0|     3|
|  2|       43|           1|     1|
|  2|       44|           0|     1|
|  2|       45|           0|     1|
+---+---------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more clear; there can be an arbitrary number of rows with values of 0 in the head_column